# Xcode 7, UI-Testing: working with UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm facing with one problem using `UITesting` framework for the xCode that Apple has introduced at WWDC 2015.
I have a UITableView and this table contains a lot of cells. Also I have a NSArray with cells titles - if cell title is contained in NSArray this cell should be tapped.
My problem is that I can't scroll table view for particular cell, because framework doesn't contain method for working with table views, only swipe gestures (down, up).

Maybe somebody knows how I can tap on particular cell in table view? Or how I can scroll table view for particular cell? 
Because when I call `tap()` method for cell which are not visible at screen - nothing happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if my answer resolved your issue, can you please accept it, thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
XCUIElementQuery *tablesQuery = self.app.tables;

XCUIElementQuery *cellQuery = [tablesQuery.cells containingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText
                                                     identifier:@"Work"];

XCUIElementQuery* cell = [cellQuery childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeStaticText];

XCUIElement* cellElement = cell.element;

[cellElement tap];
```

For scrolling the table use:

```
XCUIElementQuery *tablesQuery = self.app.tables;
XCUIElement* table = tablesQuery.element;
[table swipeUp];
```

Comment: any idea how to achieve this with Swift?

Comment: @cptdanko See my answer for Swift equivalent.

Comment: let app = XCUIApplication()
        let tablesQuery = app.tables
        let cellQuery = tablesQuery.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier: "Work")
        let cell = cellQuery.children(matching: .staticText)
        let cellElement = cell.element
        cellElement.tap()

Answer (score 5):

I recently came across a similar problem. 
An option you can try is to look for a specific title for a cell in the table, and tap on that,

for example:-

```
XCUIApplication().tables.staticTexts["identifier"].tap()
```

or

```
XCUIApplication().tables.cells.staticTexts["identifier"].tap()
```

Where "identifier" is the title of the cell you are trying to tap.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work, nothing happen after tap() :/

Answer (score 5):

Swift version for @Eugene Zhenya Gordin's answer:
**Updated for Swift 4**

```
    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    let cellQuery = tablesQuery.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier: "MyCell")
    let cell = cellQuery.children(matching: .staticText)
    let cellElement = cell.element
    cellElement.tap()

    let tableElement = tablesQuery.element
    tableElement.swipeUp()
```

Comment: these won't compile in Swift 4

Comment: @delta2flat try now

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same exact issue!

At first, I was just tapping on the cell's label, through the `.staticTexts` query. Here's another way that worked for me:

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, where you instantiate the cells, give them each a unique identifier, depending on their `titleLabel` or another property.

Example:

```
cell.accessibilityIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myCellType%@", cell.colorIdentifier];
```

Then, back in the test class, try this: (A little verbose on purpose, because it helped me understand better)

```
XCUIApplication *application = [XCUIApplication new];
XCUIElementQuery *tablesQuery = application.tables;
XCUIElementQuery *allCellsQuery = tablesQuery.cells;
XCUIElementQuery *specificCellQuery = [cellQuery matchingIdentifier:@"myCellTypeSaffron"];
XCUIElement *cell = specificCellQuery.element;

[cell tap];
```

The specific cell resolves when it's interacted with.

Hope that helps!